# How do I reprocess items in Vindictus?

Tags: vindictus

Some items such as "Shadow Fang Helm" say "Kirstie may be able to reprocess it".  I've gone to Kirstie but I can't find an option to reprocess.

Answer (score 1):

I believe "reprocessing" means it's a necessary ingredient in a crafting recipe. The name is the person who can craft with it.

For example, the [Shadow Fang Helm](http://vindictus.gamepedia.com/Shadow_Fang_Helm) is a material for Kirstie to craft [Light Battle Mail Helm](http://vindictus.gamepedia.com/Light_Battle_Mail_Helm).  The [Spiked Gnoll Club](http://vindictus.gamepedia.com/Spiked_Gnoll_Club) is used by Ferghus to craft a [Fine Spear](http://vindictus.gamepedia.com/Fine_Spear) or [Wooden Staff](http://vindictus.gamepedia.com/Wooden_Staff).